# Help with xpatch-ing a command from xkeyval: \setkeys

Tags: macros, tex-core, xkeyval, xpatch

I'm trying to patch `\setkeys` from `xkeyval`, so that it includes a mask of keys to ignore completely when `\setkeys` is called. Note that `\setkeys` in called in various macros, and there is a lots of them, so modifying the call-site is inelegant, to the extent of being infeasible. My aim is to dynamically hide and show certain fields in some type theoretic tables in an elegant and automatic fashion.

After several days of laboring and debugging, I've decided to post my question here, to see if it garners any interest.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval, xpatch, xstring, luacode, xargs}

\makeatletter
\define@cmdkey[prim]{frame}{D}{(#1)}

% Our global mask
\def\bonak@mask{}

% First we define \appendmask
\long\def\bonak@appendmask[#1]{
  \XKV@for@eo\XKV@fams\XKV@tfam{
    \def\bonak@hdr{\XKV@prefix\XKV@tfam @}
    \XKV@for@o{#1}\XKV@tempa{
      \XKV@addtolist@x\bonak@mask{\bonak@hdr\XKV@tempa}
      }
  }
}
\def\appendmask{\XKV@testopta{\XKV@testoptc\bonak@appendmask}}

% Now we patch \XKV@setkeys
\xpretocmd{\XKV@setkeys}{
  \XKV@for@o\XKV@fams\XKV@tfam{
    \def\bonak@hdr{\XKV@prefix\XKV@tfam @}
    \XKV@for@o{\bonak@mask}\XKV@tempa{
      \IfBeginWith{\XKV@tempa}{\bonak@hdr}{
        \def\XKV@tempb{\StrBehind{\XKV@tempa}{\bonak@hdr}}
        \XKV@delete#2{\XKV@tempb}\XKV@getkeyname}{}
    }
  }
}{}{}
\makeatother

% Some lua magic to join a variable number of arguments with commas
% Comma-separeated optional arguments
\begin{luacode*}
  function remove_empty(tbl)
    for i, v in ipairs(tbl) do
        if v == "" then
          table.remove(tbl, i)
          return remove_empty(tbl)
        end
    end
    return tbl
  end
  function join_with_comma(prefix, tbl)
    str = table.concat(remove_empty(tbl), ",")
    if str == "" then
      return str
    end
    return prefix .. str
  end
\end{luacode*}

\newcommandx{\joinargs}[6][2=,3=,4=,5=,6=]{\directlua{tex.sprint(join_with_comma("#1", {"\luaescapestring{#2}";"\luaescapestring{#3}";"\luaescapestring{#4}";"\luaescapestring{#5}";"\luaescapestring{#6}"}))}}

\newcommandx*{\prim}[6][2=,3=,4=,5=,6=]{
  \ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}_{#2}^{
    \joinargs{}[#3][#4][#5]}}
  \setkeys*[prim]{#1}{#6}
}
\newcommandx{\framep}[5][1=,2=,3=,4=,5=]{\prim{frame}[][#2][#3][#4][#5]}
\appendmask[prim]{frame}[D]

\begin{document}
\framep[m][n][p][][D=D]
\end{document}
```

I get:

```
[4] (./tab-frames.tex) (./tab-faces.tex
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
\inaccessible 
l.19 \end{eqntable}
```

This is not at all helpful, but such is error-reporting in LaTeX. I know the problem is related to my usage of `\XKV@delete`, and perturbing the expansion around it produces different errors. I've gone through `xkeyval`'s [code](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xkeyval/xkeyval.pdf) over and over again, hoping to gain to enlightenment, but alas: I've decided to rest for some time. I'm pretty sure it's hitting `\@nil` in `\XKV@g@tkeynames`, because defining `\@nil` makes the compile error go away, but of course, the code doesn't do anything.

My LaTeX expansion-foo isn't so great, and I *think* my problem is essentially missing some `\protect` or `\expandafter`. I'd additionally appreciate a resource like a full-fledged manual describing TeX expansion in full detail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to report that I've finished the aforementioned task, and polished it into a `xkeymask.sty`, which I present below.

```
\RequirePackage{kvoptions, xkeyval}
\ProvidesPackage{xkeymask}[2022/06/01 An extension of xkeyval with a mask]

% Option processing
\newif\ifxkeymask@prefix
\DeclareStringOption{prefix}
\AddToKeyvalOption*{prefix}{\xkeymask@prefixtrue}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\ifxkeymask@prefix
  % We patch xkeyval's \setkeys to use a mask to ignore keys
  \makeatletter
  % Our global mask
  \def\XKM@mask{}

  % First we define \appendmask
  \long\def\XKM@appendmask[#1]{
    \XKV@for@o\XKV@fams\XKV@tfam{
      \xdef\XKM@hdr{\XKV@prefix\XKV@tfam @}
      \XKV@for@o{#1}\XKV@tempa{
        % Remove spaces around key name
        \expandafter\KV@@sp@def\expandafter\XKV@tempa\expandafter{\XKV@tempa}
        \XKV@addtolist@x\XKM@mask{\XKM@hdr\XKV@tempa}
      }
    }
  }
  \def\appendmask{\XKV@testopta{\XKV@testoptc\XKM@appendmask}}

  % A quick way to clear the mask
  \def\clearmask{\global\let\XKM@mask\@empty}

  % Now we override the definition of \XKV@setkeys
  \long\def\XKM@setkeys[#1]#2{
    \XKV@checksanitizea{#2}\XKV@resb
    \let\XKV@resa\@empty
    \XKV@for@o\XKV@fams\XKV@tfam{
      \XKV@for@o\XKV@resb\XKV@tempb{
        \expandafter\XKV@g@tkeyname\XKV@tempb=\@nil\XKV@tempc
        % Remove spaces around key name
        \expandafter\KV@@sp@def\expandafter\XKV@tempc\expandafter{\XKV@tempc}
        \xdef\XKV@tempd{\XKV@prefix\XKV@tfam @\XKV@tempc}
        % If \XKV@tempd is in \XKM@mask,
        % remove the corresponding kv from \XKV@resb
        \@expandtwoargs\in@\XKV@tempd\XKM@mask
        \ifin@\else\XKV@addtolist@o\XKV@resa\XKV@tempb\fi
      }
    }
    \ifnum\XKV@depth=\z@\let\XKV@rm\@empty\fi
    \expandafter\XKV@s@tkeys\expandafter{\XKV@resa}{#1}
    \let\CurrentOption\@empty
  }

  % A dispatcher to \XKM@setkeys or \XKV@setkeys
  \long\def\XKM@setkeys@dispatch{
    \xdef\XKV@tempa{\xkeymask@prefix @}
    \ifx\XKV@prefix\XKV@tempa
      \expandafter\XKM@setkeys
    \else
      \expandafter\XKV@setkeys
    \fi
  }

  % Finally, override \setkeys itself to call the dispatcher
  \def\setkeys{\XKV@testopta{\XKV@testoptc\XKM@setkeys@dispatch}}
  \makeatother
\fi
```

Usage: After the code is working as expected with `xkeyval`, replace the import of `xkeyval` with `\usepackage[prefix=<yourprefix>]{xkeymask}`. Everything should work as expected. Now, there are two simple commands: `\appendmask`, and `\clearmask`, to be used within the body.

I present a snippet of real-world usage:

```
\input{tab-frames.tex}

% For the last two tables
\appendmask[bonak]{frame}[D]
\appendmask[bonak]{layer}[D]
\appendmask[bonak]{filler}[D, E]
\appendmask[bonak]{restrframe}[D]
\appendmask[bonak]{restrlayer}[D, d]
\appendmask[bonak]{restrfiller}[D, d]

\input{tab-faces.tex}

% For the last table,
% (1) make the {d} arguments of restr implicit
% (2) make the {D, E} arguments of coh implicit
\appendmask[bonak]{cohframe}[D]
\appendmask[bonak]{cohlayer}[D]
\appendmask[bonak]{cohfiller}[D, E]

\input{tab-coh.tex}
\clearmask
```